# How to get the first level child element of a DOM element retrieved by document.getElementById in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, parent-child, selector

I have an `outer` element that retrieved by `document.getElementById` (I can't change this part as the `outer` variable was passed in by other code). How to get its direct child element that have class `inner`? I've tried `outer.querySelectorAll(".inner")`, which will get all `.inner` elements (see below demo). I only want the *direct child* and have `.inner`. I also tried  `outer.querySelectorAll("> .inner")`, but it doesn't work. How can I do that?

```js
var outer = document.getElementById("outer");
var all = outer.querySelectorAll(".inner");
all.forEach(function(e){
    e.style.border = "1px solid red";
});
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div class="inner">inner</div>
  <div id="test">
    <div class="inner">inner2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `outer` is already in a variable, you can use `:scope` at the start of a query string with `querySelectorAll` to "select" the element the `querySelectorAll` is being called on:

```js
var outer = document.getElementById("outer");
outer.querySelectorAll(":scope > .inner").forEach((e) => {
  e.style.border = "1px solid red";
});
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div class="inner">inner</div>
  <div id="test">
    <div class="inner">inner2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you *don't* have to have `outer` already in a variable, it would be easier to use the plain query string `#outer > .inner`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#outer > .inner").forEach((e) => {
  e.style.border = "1px solid red";
});
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div class="inner">inner</div>
  <div id="test">
    <div class="inner">inner2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Rather than iterating over all child elements, a different approach would be to toggle a class on `outer`, while having a CSS rule which applies to direct children of `outer` while `outer` has that class:

```js
document.querySelector('#outer').classList.add('red');
```

```css
#outer.red > .inner {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div class="inner">inner</div>
  <div id="test">
    <div class="inner">inner2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I didn't know `:scope`. I can only accept your answer in 10 minutes.